# How do I generate random subnormal numbers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, floating-point, ieee-754

I'd like to verify a piece of code works on subnormal numbers, so I'd like to generate a bunch of random subnormal single-precision numbers (including zero). How can I do this?

Solutions such as dividing by a large number to get a subnormal may just round to zero or, in the best case, probably won't give an even distribution.

`nextafter` iteration could work, but it'd be slow!

Comment: @Evg I have found noting in the answer and maybe the question too, when short, that this is part of a [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) helps prevent such votes.  Without that, the question, on first glance, looks like a no-effort one.

Answer (score 2):

First, recall that a

- [single-precision (float)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is SignBit + 8 Exponent Bits + 23 Mantissa Bits (32 bits total)
- [double-precision (double)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) is SignBit + 11 Exponent Bits + 52 Mantissa Bits (64 bits total)
- a [subnormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number) is a floating-point whose exponent bits are all zero

With this in hand we have the following strategy:

1. Draw 32/64 bits uniformly. We won't need all of these bits, but it'll be more convenient and faster to draw them this way. We'll just randomize as many bits as a floating-point number requires and then...
2. Mask out the exponent bits so they are zero
3. Convert the bit pattern into a floating-point number

A caveat is that the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the exponent bit mask must match the [endianness of the floating-point values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating_point). This is the case for most hardware, but you should test it if you want to be exceptionally rigorous or are working on something exotic.

All that said, we get this code:

```cpp
// Compile with: clang++.par -O3 -march=native test2.cpp --std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror

#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

template<std::floating_point T>
class uniform_subnormal_distribution {
  private:
    // float is SignBit + 8 Exponent Bits + 23 Mantissa Bits
    static constexpr uint32_t subnormal_mask32 = 0x807FFFFF;
    // double is SignBit + 11 Exponent Bits + 52 Mantissa Bits
    static constexpr uint64_t subnormal_mask64 = 0x800FFFFFFFFFFFFF;
  public:
    template<class Engine>
    T operator()(Engine& eng) const {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>){
            std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> dist;
            // Get uniformaly distributed bits
            const uint32_t bits = dist(eng);
            // Make the exponent all zeros
            const uint32_t subnormal_bits = bits & subnormal_mask32;
            // Retrieve a floating-point value from the bits
            return std::bit_cast<float, uint32_t>(subnormal_bits);
        } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>){
            std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t> dist;
            const uint64_t bits = dist(eng);
            const uint64_t subnormal_bits = bits & subnormal_mask32;
            return std::bit_cast<double, uint64_t>(subnormal_bits);
        } else {
            // can't use 'false' -- expression has to depend on a template parameter
            static_assert(!sizeof(T*), "Unsupported floating-point type");
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    uniform_subnormal_distribution<float> dist;
    std::vector<float> res;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        const auto float_val = dist(mt);
        std::cout<<float_val<<std::endl;
        res.push_back(float_val);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Draw 32/64 bits uniformly" --> Drawing 24 bits is sufficient.  23 for the significant and 1 for the sign.

Comment: "a subnormal is a floating-point whose exponent bits are all zero" --> Detail: Not quite.  +/- 0.0 encoding has a biased exponent of 0 yet in IEEE 754-2008, it specifies "In this standard, zero is neither normal nor subnormal."  C distinguishes between zero and subnormal.  I suspect C++ follows that.    Perhaps the question better as "How do I generate random subnormal numbers and zeros? as zero is not, by theses standards, specified as a sub-normal.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I generate random subnormal numbers? (single-precision)

1. As the binary precision of single-precision is commonly 23 bits, generate 24 random bits: 1 for the sign and 23 for the significand.  Otherwise adjust the size.
2. Scale the 23-bit unsigned integer value by `r23 * std::numeric_limits<float>::min() / 0x800000u /* 2^23 */`.
3. Apply the random sign bit.

Not that this may also generate +/- 0.0.  By spec, zeroes are not sub-normals, yet I suspect for OP's purposes generating a zero is OK.  If not, add a test for zero.

No endian issues.

Comment: I concur with a general preference to generate subnormal numbers by arithmetic, as indicated in this answer, rather than by bit manipulation. However, if the purpose is for testing in an environment where the behavior with subnormals is questionable, it may be necessary to generate them by bit manipulation.